# Adding a relative path to an absolute path in python

Tags: python, filenames, relative-path

Assuming I have a absolute path and a relative path

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
relpath = '../../folder/file'
```

How do I 'add' these two path together without the `../..`s, is there a module that does this? I can't find anything so far. I'm thinking of a format like:

```
mypath = some_module.function(abspath, relpath)
```

Instead of doing

```
mypath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(abspath))), folder, file)
```

Which I think is too bothersome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `join` them and use [normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath):

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.join(abspath, relpath))
```

From `normpath` doc:

> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level
>   references so that A//B, A/B/, A/./B and A/foo/../B all become A/B.

---

You could also use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module since Python 3.4:

```
from pathlib import Path

abspath = Path('/home/xxxx/yyy')
relpath = Path('../../folder/file')
(abspath / relpath).resolve()
# PosixPath('/home/xxxx')
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I want to know!